# Como gestionar cada uno de los elementos de un RecyclerView al margen de su posicion

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Mi app tiene un RecyclerView que muestra textos a su vez tengo una ImageView al lado de cada uno que me permite indicar ese texto como favorito(y guardar su estado).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas tengo la funcionalidad de poder buscar en mi RecyclerView cadenas de texto, lo cual al coincidir devuelve las posiciones de los texto, mostrando asi el *mismo* list view pero mas reducido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

--Mi problema es que si yo marco como favorito el primer texto (posicion 1) y luego hago una busqueda , en este nuevo listview donde posiblemente el primer elemento sea el 7º de la antigua lista, este estara marcado ya que gestiono los iconos en base a la posicion de texto en el RecyclerView.
En el siguiente video se ve el problema.
Me gustaria saber si existe otra forma de gestionar mis iconos sin depender de la posicion en el RecyclerView.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo...

[VIDEO DEMOSTRACION](https://s3.amazonaws.com/img0.recordit.co/vxxu8GWH45.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAUQ5RURZ7ND2T2B6I&Expires=1598490885&Signature=OB01VYHorLlpj6jQvNR0B7I02zQ%3D)

Dado que no se exactamente que parte del codigo proporcionales, les dejo el proyecto completo aqui :

[Enlace a Github](https://github.com/jmlgomez73/ProtocolosTCAE)

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
La mejor forma de describir tu situación es incluyendo el código relevante a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se resuelve asignando un id único a cada nota. Tu código quedaría así:

IndexBusqueda

```
public class IndexBusqueda {
    //Creamos variables
    public int id;// ID único para cada nota
    public String index;
    public boolean realizado;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ArrayList<IndexBusqueda> getlistaIndexBusqueda() {
        IndexBusqueda objetoNota = null;
        ArrayList<IndexBusqueda> lista = new ArrayList<IndexBusqueda>();
        //Arreglo de IndexBusqueda
        String[] arrayIndexBusqueda = new String[]{/*tus strings*/};

        //Arreglo de si se realizo o no la copia
        boolean[] arrayRealizado = new boolean[]{/*tus booleanos*/};
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayIndexBusqueda.length; i++) {
                String nota = arrayIndexBusqueda[i];
                boolean realizado = arrayRealizado[i];
                //Agregamos los elementos al objeto
                objetoNota = new IndexBusqueda(nota, realizado);
                objetoNota.setId(i);//Asignamos el Id de acuerda a su posición en la lista (no la posición en el recycler)
                //agregamos el objeto a nuesta lista asi hasta que se llene con todos los elementos
                lista.add(objetoNota);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Retornamos la lista
        return lista;
    }
}
```

RecyclerAdaptador

```
public void bind(final IndexBusqueda nota, final int posicion, final OnItemClickListener listener, final ImageView fav) {
            //Agregamos la nota a nuestro texview del adaptador
            txtnota.setText(nota.getNota());
            //AQUÍ ESTÁ EL CAMBIO
            if (!Favoritos.getInstance().esFavorito(nota.getId())) {
                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_border);
            } else {
                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_black);
            }

            Log.d("Nota",nota.getNota());
        }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, la verdad no se como no se me ocurrio algo tan tonto :((, llevaba mucho tiempo pensando como arreglarlo..